# Complex and recursive sequences

Tags: complex-analysis

Study the convergences of the following sequences:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^{n}}{(n+1)^{2}} $$

and $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} $$

Where $a_{n}$ is defined recursively by: $$a_{0} = 1+i $$ $$a_{n+1} = \frac{(2+3i)n}{7+(5i)n^{2}}a_{n} $$

I don't know how to do this two excercises, if anyone can help I really appreciate.

Comment: Do you mean $1^n$ as the numerator in the first series? Or actually $i^n$? In both cases, have a look at what it means for a series to be absolutely convergent.

Comment: @SomeMathStudent Oh, sorry, I'll fix right now. Yes, is $i^{n}$.

Comment: @SomeMathStudent the first excercise is ready. Thanks :D

Comment: The first series is $~\text{Catalan}+i\cdot\dfrac{\pi^2}{48}$. See [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant) and [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, since you've already done the first one by absolute convergence, you might try that for the second series as well.

Again, since the expressions are ugly enough that we don't really want to do much with them, we look at the absolutes. We have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2+3i)n}{7+(5i)n^2}$.

Now, if we imagine we had absolutes here. Then we'd get $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=|\frac{(2+3i)n}{7+(5i)n^2}|\geq|\frac{\sqrt{5}n}{5n^2-7}|>\frac{\sqrt{5}n}{4n^2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4n}$ for nearly all $n$ - provided I didn't miscalculate somewhere along the way, I leave the reasoning to you.

Once you're here, I'll only say ratio test...

Comment: The exercise is ready, thank you very much! I took calculus long time ago and I forgot some things. :)